# Meteor Design Templates

Tags: javascript, css, html, meteor

Meteor seems great in that it has a whole lot of backend modules that can be quickly inserted in, but are they any front end templates out there? All the ones for jQuery/Bootstrap will not work without heavy modification to Meteor's expected syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you look at the packaging system, atmospherejs.com?  At Differential, we have created a bunch of stuff to make the job of building MVP's much easier, like the [ShareIt](https://github.com/Differential/shareit) package or things like [Accounts Entry](https://github.com/Differential/accounts-entry) for doing a nice bootstrap3 login interface.

Comment: Thanks for your response Josh. I looked at atmospherejs, lots of good stuff there, but its not very well organized/hard to determine visual of some of the packages. I was thinking similar to wrapbootstrap [link](http://wrapbootstrap.com)  Your differential group has some awesome stuff -- nice work.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look!  I guess I should get a screenshot up in my package at least :)